# HowTo: Raise a event where event handler has a ref bool parameter

Tags: rhino-mocks

using RhinoMocks I would like to raise a event, where the event handler signature looks like:
`MyEventHandler(int a value, ref bool handled) {..}`

If I use:
`myMock.Raise(x => x.MyEventHandler += null, aValue, handled);`

I get the following Error message:
System.InvalidOperationException: Parameter #2 is System.Boolean but should be System.Boolean&

I tried it with:
`myMock.Raise(x => x.MyEventHandler += null, aValue, ref Arg<bool>.Ref(Is.Anything(), handled).Dummy);`
but that doesn't even compile...

What Is the right way to raise this event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on following example

```
[Test]
public void RaiseEvent()
{
    var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IEventsRaiser>();
    mock.GetEventRaiser(x => x.MyEvent += null).Raise(1, Arg<bool>.Ref(new Anything(), true).Dummy);
}

public delegate void MyEventHandler(int a, ref bool handled);

public interface IEventsRaiser
{
    event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
}
```